# Unable to integrate user-defined function

Tags: integration, matlab

I defined a function to return the actual roots of a quartic function.   theCentralTrace[t] is an NDSolve solution of the  trace over the function of a particular branch. But this is only approximate.  I wish to obtain high-precision values of the function over the trace by solving for the roots with NSolve  and then selecting the root that matches the (approximate) value of the trace.  The function getDigits returns floating point numbers as a sequence of 5 digits so that Position can find the root that matches the value of the trace.  I can plot this function via:

```
Plot[myFunction[t],{t,tStart,tEnd}]
```

but if I attempt to integrate it via:

```
NIntegrate[myFunction[t],{t,tStart,tEnd}]
```

I receive errors:  The conditional in the code return an unevaluated 't' so Position fails.  I was wondering if someone could help me fix this.  Thanks.

```
  myFunction[t_] := Module[{cDigits, fVal, 
    fDigits, pos, cVal},
  cVal = theCentralTrace[t];
  cDigits = getDigits[cVal, 5];
  fVal = w /. NSolve[theFunction == 0 /. z - 
      > rnorm Exp[I t], w];
  fDigits = getDigits[fVal, 5];
  pos = Position[fDigits, cDigits[[1]]];
  If[Length[pos] == 0,
     Print[t];
     Abort[];
  ];
  Re[fVal[[pos[[1, 1]]]]]
  ];
```

Comment: I added the matlab tag. But this appears to be a programming question, not a question about the mathematics itself. In this case, you would be better off asking it at StackOverflow

Comment: Is this meant to be Mathematica and not MATLAB?

Comment: yes it was.  I created a thread there and the question was answered unfortunately it does not solve my problem regarding obtaining accurate results of highly oscillating integrals.  I plan to create a new thread there with more specific information about my exact problem